# Select ID from one table and insert in another table with while loop

Tags: php, mysql, sql

The code below works on three tables:

`iStock, iInvoicebook, iInvoiceitems`

`iInvoicebook` and `iInvoiceitems` are linked bt `ID` and `dInvoicebookFKEY`,

`iStock` - This table stores all products with clients name and quantity. To generate an invoice, the code gets `DISTINCT` clients and inserts to `iInvoicebook`.

After this, the code inserts all product details from the `iStock` table to `iInvoiceitems`.

The code below mostly works, except that when I try to get `iInvoicebook`  `ID` and try to insert it (as foreign key) in `iInvoiceitems`, it inserts the old ID of `iInvoicebook` based on `clientID`.

I want the newly added `ID` of `iInvoicebook` to be inserted in `iInvoiceitems`.

```
if($CurrDate == $LastDayofMonth) 
{
    // Get Distinct clients and add it into Main table  "Invoicebook"
    $getClients = "SELECT  DISTINCT iClientName AS CLT,  Product from stock where quantity > '0' AND InvoiceDate ='$LastDayCM'";
    $stmt = ExecuteQuery($getClients); // execute the query
    if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) { // check condition: if record count is greater than 0

        while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) { // begin of loop
            $NewNo = Executerow("Select max(ibInvoiceNo) AS NEXTNO from invoicebook");
            $Nor = $NewNo["NEXTNO"] + 1 ;
            $instInInvoice = ExecuteStatement("INSERT INTO invoicebook (ibClientName, Product, InvoiceNo)
            Values( '".$row["CLT"]."','".$row["Product"]."', '".$Nor."')");  
        }
    }

    // Now no Disticnt value. Get all stock values of related client and insert into     "invoiceitems"  table
    $getDetails = "select iClientID, product, quantity from stock where quantity > '0' AND InvoiceDate ='$LastDayCM' AND  iClientName = '".$getClients["iClientName"]."'";

    $dstmt = ExecuteQuery($getDetails); // execute the query

    if ($dstmt->rowCount() > 0) { // check condition: if record count is greater than 0
        while ($row = $dstmt->fetch()) { // begin of loop
            $InvoiceFKEY = Executerow("Select INVID from invoicebook where dClientID = '".$row["iClientID"]."'");
            $DetailsInsrt = ExecuteStatement("INSERT INTO invoiceitems (dproduct, dQuantity, dRate, dInvoicebookFKEY)
            Values( '".$row["product"]."','".$row["quantity"]."','".$rate."', '".$InvoiceFKEY["INVID"]."')");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Formatting tip: highlight code, click `{}`.

Comment: For future reference: [How do I format my posts?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), [ask], the [tour].

Answer (score 0):

here your code with some comments :

```
if ($CurrDate == $LastDayofMonth) {
    // Get Distinct clients and add it into Main table  "Invoicebook"
    $getClients = "SELECT  DISTINCT iClientName AS CLT,  Product from stock where quantity > '0' AND InvoiceDate ='$LastDayCM'";
    $stmt = ExecuteQuery($getClients); // execute the query
    if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) { // check condition: if record count is greater than 0
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) { // begin of loop
            $NewNo = Executerow("Select max(ibInvoiceNo) AS NEXTNO from invoicebook");
            $Nor = intval($NewNo["NEXTNO"]) + 1;
            $instInInvoice = ExecuteStatement("INSERT INTO invoicebook (ibClientName, Product, InvoiceNo) "
                    . " Values ( '" . $row["CLT"] . "','" . $row["Product"] . "', '" . $Nor . "') "
                    . " on duplicate key update InvoiceNo='{$Nor}'"); //EDIT : Dont know but should get PK key 
                    // => this could generate multiple line in you DB
                    // => and don't know your DB structure but for me, should be better to link with stock.iClientID than stock.iClientName
                    // 
        }
    }

    /**
     * From here why create second loop?
     * Should have fonction "get_last_id" from your DB object and if the field invoicebook.INVID is AI should get last one
     * 
     */
    
    
    
    // Now no Disticnt value. Get all stock values of related client and insert into     "invoiceitems"  table
    $getDetails = "select iClientID, product, quantity from stock where quantity > '0' AND InvoiceDate ='$LastDayCM' "
            . " AND  iClientName = '" . $getClients["iClientName"] . "'"; // - EDIT : this is empty var => NULL

    $dstmt = ExecuteQuery($getDetails); // execute the query

    if ($dstmt->rowCount() > 0) { // check condition: if record count is greater than 0
        while ($row = $dstmt->fetch()) { // begin of loop
            $InvoiceFKEY = Executerow("Select INVID from invoicebook where dClientID = '" . $row["iClientID"] . "'");
            $DetailsInsrt = ExecuteStatement("INSERT INTO invoiceitems (dproduct, dQuantity, dRate, dInvoicebookFKEY)
            Values( '" . $row["product"] . "','" . $row["quantity"] . "','" . $rate . "', '" . $InvoiceFKEY["INVID"] . "')");
            //Same : duplicate key => what the frequence of this routine?
            // ($CurrDate == $LastDayofMonth) => I guess once by day, everyday and run only last month day
            // Or action from you : mean you can run this script more than once a day => duplicated data
            // $LastDayCM == $CurrDate  == $LastDayofMonth  ??????
        }
    }
}
```

If I understand well, you should maybe change your function with a code like this :

```
if ($CurrDate == $LastDayofMonth) {
    //First should escape your variable
    $getClients = sprintf("SELECT  DISTINCT `iClientName` AS CLT,`iClientID` as 'IdClient', `Product`,`quantity` " // should
            . " from `stock` "
            . " where `quantity`>%d AND InvoiceDate='%s' "
            , 0 // quantity
            , escapeFunction($LastDayCM) //mysqli_real_escape($linkSql, $LastDayCM) : don't know where your data come from
    );
    $stmt = ExecuteQuery($getClients); // execute the query
    if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) { // Useless for me
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) { // begin of loop
            $NewNo = Executerow("Select max(`ibInvoiceNo`) AS NEXTNO from `invoicebook`");
            $Nor = intval($NewNo["NEXTNO"]) + 1; // NEXTNO can be null if no data 
            $instInInvoice = ExecuteStatement(
                    sprintf("INSERT INTO `invoicebook` (`dClientID`,`ibClientName`, `Product`, `InvoiceNo`) "
                            . " Values (%d, '%s','%s', %d) "
                            , $row['IdClient'] // add ID ??? and not sure about column name
                            , escapeFunction($row["CLT"])
                            , escapeFunction($row["Product"])
                            , $Nor
                    )
            );
            //Get last id 2 options : get_last_id function or new select statement : 
            //option 1 : better
            $INVID = getLastIdFunction();
            //Option 2 : depend of your DB structure
            $InvoiceFKEY = Executerow(
                    sprintf("Select INVID from `invoicebook`"
                            . "  where dClientID =%d and InvoiceNo=%d"
                            , $row['IdClient']
                            , $Nor
                    )
            );
            $tmpStatement = ExecuteQuery($InvoiceFKEY); // execute the query
            $INVID = $tmpStatement->fetch()['INVID'];
            //Add new invoiceitems            
            $DetailsInsrt = ExecuteStatement(sprintf("INSERT INTO `invoiceitems` "
                            . " (`dproduct`, `dQuantity`, `dRate`, `dInvoicebookFKEY`) Values "
                            . " ( '%s',%d,%0.2f, %d)"
                            , escapeFunction($row["Product"])
                            , $row["quantity"]
                            , $rate // where come from? format? 00000.00 ???
                            , $INVID
                    )
            );
            ExecuteQuery($DetailsInsrt);
        }
    }
}
```

Without DB structure and more details, hard to go further